Yes/No Popup on PySimpleGUI
How do I use yes/no popups on PySimpleGUI? I've searched everywhere, but the answers just aren't clear on this.
At the moment, I am just trying to make a simple yes/no program so I can get my head around this.
Here's my code so far:
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time

sg.popup("Welcome to this random file.")
result = sg.popup_yes_no("Would you like to continue?")

if(result == "yes"):
    sg.popup("Great! You have chosen to continue the process.")

elif(result == "no"):
    sg.popup("Exiting process...")
    sg.popup("See you!")
    time.sleep(3)
    exit()

else:
    sg.popup("Invalid input")



popup_yes_no return "Yes" or "No" or None,not "yes" or "no". Refer https://docs.pysimplegui.com/en/latest/call_reference/tkinter/popups/popup_yes_no/

You have to turn yes into Yes and no to No. You can find this by printing the result, like this:
result = sg.popup_yes_no("Would you like to continue?")
print(result)

So the corrected code would be this:
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time

sg.popup("Welcome to this random file.")
result = sg.popup_yes_no("Would you like to continue?")

if(result == "Yes"):
    sg.popup("Great! You have chosen to continue the process.")

elif(result == "No"):
    sg.popup("Exiting process...")
    sg.popup("See you!")
    time.sleep(3)
    exit()

else:
    sg.popup("Invalid input")

My advice is to always use some sort of debugging, maybe through debugging libraries or through print.

the "always use some sort of debugging" part...... print is the gold standard :-)

@MikefromPSG Thanks... I always use it to. Even on fast browser (you can see my about section if you want to know what i'm talking about)

@user26149746 You're welcome. Would you mind clicking on the check mark, so others know this is a working answer?

For what it's worth, I generally use this call in an if statement as it's always used eventually with an if.  if sg.popup_yes_no('Do you want to continue?') != 'Yes':     sg.popup('Aborting');exit().  There is rarely a need to store in an intermediate variable.  It's usually "Yes" or anything else (like No or window was closed with X)

You can create a function to normalize the input by converting the user response to a standardized format. This way, you can handle variations in input more gracefully.
Here's your updated code with a normalization function:
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time

def normalize_input(response):
    if response.lower() == "yes":
        return "Yes"
    elif response.lower() == "no":
        return "No"
    else:
        return response

sg.popup("Welcome to this random file.")
result = sg.popup_yes_no("Would you like to continue?")

# Normalize the input
normalized_result = normalize_input(result)

if normalized_result == "Yes":
    sg.popup("Great! You have chosen to continue the process.")

elif normalized_result == "No":
    sg.popup("Exiting process...")
    sg.popup("See you!")
    time.sleep(3)
    exit()

else:
    sg.popup("Invalid input")

